# How to conditionally evaluate bash script

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

To view the installed libraries on an environment I run this code within a Jupyter Python notebook cell :

```
%%bash
pip freeze
```

This works, but how to conditionally execute this code ?

This is my attempt :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x1):
    if(x1 == True):
        f2()
    return x1

interact(f , x1 = False)


def f2():
    %%bash 
    pip freeze
```

But evaluating the cell throws error :

```
  File "<ipython-input-186-e8a8ec97ab2d>", line 15
    pip freeze
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To generate the checkbox I'm using ipywidgets : https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets

Update : 
Running `pip freeze` within `check_call` returns 0 results : 
[image]

Running

```
    %%bash 
    pip freeze
```

Returns installed libraries so 0 is not correct.

Is `subprocess.check_call("pip freeze", shell=True)` correct ?

Update 2 :

This works :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
import subprocess

def f(View):
    if(View == True):
        f2()

interact(f , View = False)


def f2():
    print(subprocess.check_output(['pip', 'freeze']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the standard Python way:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['pip', 'freeze']))
```

Then your function will work in any Python environment.

Comment: @blue-sky The result code from `check_call` is zero when the command succeeded, so it's entirely correct (but apparently not what you expect; but then what *do* you expect?)

Comment: Though you want to avoid the unnecessary and pesky `shell=True`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @blue-sky: Try the updated version--with explicit printing.

Answer (score 1):

The short explanation is that the notebook has interactive commands which are handled by the notebook itself, before the Python interpreter even sees them.  `%%bash` is an example of such a command; you cannot put this in Python code, because it's not Python.

Using `bash` doesn't actually add anything here *per se;* using the shell offers many interactive benefits, and of course, in an interactive notebook, offering the user access to the shell is a powerful mechanism for allowing users to execute external processes; but in this particular case, with noninteractive execution, there are no actual benefits from putting the shell between yourself and `pip`, so you might simply want

```
 import subprocess
 if some_condition:
     p = subprocess.run(['pip', 'freeze'],
         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

(Notice the absence of `shell=True` because we don't need or want the shell here.)

If you want the captured exit code or the output from `pip freeze` they are available as attributes of the returned object `p`.  See the [`subprocess.run` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) for details.  Briefly, `p.returncode` will be 0 if the command succeeded, and the output will be in `p.stdout`.

Older versions of Python had a diverse collection of special-purpose wrappers around `subprocess.Popen` like `check_call`, `check_output`, etc. but these have all been subsumed by `subprocess.run` in recent versions.  If you need to support Python versions before 3.5, the legacy functions are still available, but they should arguably be avoided in new code.